# How would I get sAMAccountName and other user attributes from an input file of email addresses?

Tags: powershell

For the post answered Oct 31 '17 at 13:06:
Q:

> I have a .txt file with a bunch of email addresses and I need get corresponding login names and export them into another file.

A:

```
Get-Content -Path "c:\users-input.txt" | %{ Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $_} } | Select-Object SamAccountName | Export-CSV -Path "c:\users.csv"
```

Excellent, concise, single like example. Thanks!

Can you provide an example for outputing multiple attributes of the user accounts (ex: sAMAccountName, userPrincipalName, displayName, mail, userAccountControl) based on the input file being a list of email addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Add the desired property names to the `-Properties` retrieved by `Get-ADUser` (`SAMAccountName` and `UserPrincipalName` will already be part of the default property set) and then specify the full property list selected by `Select-Object`:

```
Get-Content -Path "c:\users-input.txt" | %{ 
    Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $_} -Properties displayName,mail,userAccountControl
} | Select-Object SamAccountName,userPrincipalName,displayName,mail,userAccountControl | Export-CSV -Path "c:\users.csv"
```